# generate multi chart with forloop

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an array that contains several arrays, and I want to generate several charts, by looping over this arrays.

```
<div class="container_report">
    <canvas id="myChart1" ></canvas>
</div>

<div class="container_report">
    <canvas id="myChart2" ></canvas>
</div>

<div class="container_report">
    <canvas id="myChart3" ></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>

    
    allData =[{'Cartes ': 1, 'écheques ': 1, 'Dominos': 3, 'Dames ': 1, 'qst': 'Quelles jeux préférez vous le plus ?'},
                {'En solo': 1, 'Avec des amies ': 4, 'En ligne ': 1, 'qst': 'Comment aimez vous jouer ?'},
                {'Le sport': 2, 'Voir la télé': 3, 'Passer du temps avec vos proches': 1, 'La lecture ': 0, 'qst': 'Quelles activité vous pratiquez en sortant du travaille ?'}
            ]
    var allValues =[]
    var xValue = []
    var yValue = []
    var allxValue = []
    var allyValue = []

    for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++){
        xValue = []
        yValue = []
        for (const property in allData[i]) {
            if(property != 'qst'){
                xValue.push(property)
            }
            if(!isNaN(allData[i][property])){
                yValue.push(allData[i][property])
            }
           
        }
        allxValue.push(xValue)
        allyValue.push(yValue)
    }

    var ctxs = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
        for(let i = 0; i <= ctxs.length;i++){                  
            console.log(ctxs[i].id)
            for(let z = 0; z < allxValue.length; z++){
                for(let y = 0; y < allyValue.length; y++){
                    var idiv = document.querySelector('#'+ctxs[i].id).getContext('2d');
                    const chart = new Chart(ctxs[i].id, {
                        type: "doughnut",
                        data: {
                          labels: allxValue[z],
                          datasets: [{   
                            data: allyValue[y]
                          }]
                        },
                        options: {}
                      });     
                }
            }
                
        }

</script>
```

but i get this error in console:

Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart1' can be reused.
at new Mn

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting an error as it's trying to create multiple charts with the same id. Can you try modifying your loop by using the index to create unique id for each chart:

```js
    for(let i = 0; i <= ctxs.length;i++){
      console.log(ctxs[i].id)
      for(let z = 0; z < allxValue.length; z++){
        for(let y = 0; y < allyValue.length; y++){
          var idiv = document.querySelector('#myChart' + (i + 1)).getContext('2d');
          const chart = new Chart('myChart' + (i + 1), {
            type: "doughnut",
            data: {
              labels: allxValue[z],
              datasets: [{   
                data: allyValue[y]
              }]
            },
            options: {}
          });     
        }
      }
    }
```

This will create charts with IDs `myChart1`, `myChart2`, and `myChart3`, which should fix the error you are seeing.

I hope this helps!

Comment: i got the same error